# Multiple dropdown menu with bootstrap is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have this html code:

```
<html><head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            MAIN
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Dropdown Menu 1
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>Sub submenu</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>B</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

And the problem is that When I drop down the "MAIN" menu and i see there is a "Dropdown Menu 1"....but if i close the main dropdown...I see it on the developer tool that  the open class added to the  second dropdown but the first lost the open class...What can be the problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you please give more info, what you want exactly?

Comment: I not see the "Sub submenu" dropdown...

Comment: I think Plunker will help more in understanding your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/26fy9yxm/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Main <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Dropdown Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

External code:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap component designed for multilevel dropdowns.

**Component dependencies :**

Requires jQuery, Bootsrap 3.x CSS and JavaScript files. Depends on Bootstrap Dropdown component and animate.css if want to use animations.

**Bootstrap compatibility :**

Dropdownhover is fully compatible with Bootstrap's native Dropdown component. They two can be applied to the same item, providing hover and click events support. On small devices hover event is ignored.

Check this link  [Bootstrap dropdown hover](https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.linkbtn').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(document).click(function(){
   $(".dropdown-submenu").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: you should explain your answer a bit